# Dynamic T-SQL WITH Statement Error

Tags: sql-server

I am building a dynamic T-SQL script and running into some errors.

```
    PRINT 'Convert References into XML fields'
    SET @query = N';WITH DCODES AS (' +
                'SELECT [id],[Codes],' +
                'CAST(''<M>'' + REPLACE([Codes],'','' , ''</M><M>'') + ''</M>'' AS XML) AS [XML_Codes],' +
                'CAST(''<M>'' + REPLACE(REPLACE([Descriptions],''&'',''AND''),'','',''</M><M>'') + ''</M>'' AS XML) AS [XML_Desc] ' +
                'FROM  ##' + @system_name + '_Temp)'

 EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

The code works if I write the statement as a static statement. When I run this in my dynamic script this error.

```
--Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
--Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I tried to rewrite it, but I still get this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing line below

```
SET @query = N';WITH DCODES AS (' +
                'SELECT [id],[Codes],' +
                'CAST(''<M>'' + REPLACE([Codes],'','' , ''</M><M>'') + ''</M>'' AS XML) AS [XML_Codes],' +
                'CAST(''<M>'' + REPLACE(REPLACE([Descriptions],''&'',''AND''),'','',''</M><M>'') + ''</M>'' AS XML) AS [XML_Desc] ' +
                'FROM  ##' + @system_name + '_Temp) select * from DCODES' -- you are missing this
```